# awk to write different columns from different lines into single line of output file?

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop

I am using a while do loop to read in from a file that contains a list of hostnames, run a command against the host list, and input specific data from the results into a second file.  I need the output to be from line 33 column 3 and line 224 column 7, output to a single line in the second file.  I can do it for either one or the other but having trouble getting it to work for both.  example:

```
while read i; do 
    /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpgetconfig -M $i |\
        awk -v j=33 -v k=3 'FNR == j {print $k}' > /tmp/clientversion.txt
done < /tmp/clientlist.txt
```

Any hints or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
awk 'NR==33{a=$3}NR==224{print a,$7}'
```

This saves the value in the third column of line 33 to the variable `a`, then prints it out along with the seventh column of line 224.

However, you're currently overwriting the file `/tmp/clientversion.txt` every iteration of the `while` loop. Assuming you want the file to contain all of the output once the loop has run, you should move the redirection outside the loop:

```
while read -r i; do
    /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpgetconfig -M $i |\
        awk 'NR==33{a=$3}NR==224{print a,$7}'
done < /tmp/clientlist.txt > /tmp/clientversion.txt
```

As a bonus, I have added the `-r` switch to `read` (see [related discussion here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r)). Depending on the contents of your input file, you might also want to use double quotes around `"$i"` as well.

Comment: Facepalm!  Thanks, I tend to make it harder than it needs to be!  Testing had only been against a single line of data in the read file so far so I hadn't found the redirect error either.

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted by click the check mark ✓ next to it.